# Jquery add title attribute with data from JSON call

Tags: jquery, json, attributes, each

I'm trying to dynamically add titles to a number of images using values obtained from a JSON call.

This is what I have so far

```
$(".watch_view img").each(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/T2aMBeeM4yw?v=2&alt=jsonc',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {   
    song_title = json.data.title;// song title is retrieved without issue                           
    }   
    });

   alert(song_title); //this to be removed
   //the title attr below is only added when the above alert is in place    
   $(this).attr('title', song_title);
   $(this).attr('alt', "This works everytime"); 
   });
```

Now the above works but only when I "stop" the process by adding in the unwanted alert - I can only guess that the code is executing before it has retrieved the data from the JSON call (?) and the alert enables it to catch up.

I imagine I need another function that executes after the JSON call or for the code to go into the 'success' function but I'm not sure how to keep hold of the 'this' element if that is the case.

Help and advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: SUCCESSS is that fucntion!!! Have you tried using $(this) inside success. AFAIR it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: It doesn't throw an error inside the success (whatever it is) but it does not add the title attr.  An alert in that location shows the correct data is retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript. It means the browser will not be unresponsive while communication with server is in progress.

When you call `$.ajax(...)` function, the script continue after it, not waiting for the response (you can configure it to wait, but then it would be a **synchronous** call).

When the server returns with success, you should respond to that event, thus, your response handling code must be in `success` function body:

```
$(".watch_view img").each(function (index,element) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/T2aMBeeM4yw?v=2&alt=jsonc',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            song_title = json.data.title; // song title is retrieved without issue                           
            $(element).attr('title', song_title);
            $(element).attr('alt', "This works everytime");
        }
    });

});
```

In your old code, the alert was reached before the server returned. When you placed a breakpoint, it worked because there was enough time for the server to return an answer while you were doing your human-time handling :)

**Update**

Additionally, you should know that `this` inside the `success` callback refers to the returned data, overriding the expected `this` for the `each` (which would be the iterated element). You have to actually declare the params for the `each` call, so that you can refer back to them inside the success call.

Comment: Moving it inside the success returns nothing in the attributes (not even for the fixed alt attribute)

Comment: Could you be more specific? You just stated in your question that `song_title = json.data.title;` works ok. What specifically is not working now?

Comment: sorry - if I have alert(song_title) it show the correct data, however the attributes remain blank.

Comment: Sorry guys but still not working - I've popped it into JSfiddle.  Maybe somebody could check my sanity? http://jsfiddle.net/VT6vP/3/

Comment: Adrian - many thanks, your update sorted the issue.  Missed it whilst fiddling with jsfiddle - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".watch_view img").each(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/T2aMBeeM4yw?v=2&alt=jsonc',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {   
        song_title = json.data.title;// song title is retrieved without issue 

       $(this).attr('title', song_title);
       $(this).attr('alt', "This works everytime");                           
    }   
    });
});
```

You need to use the success callback properly. Hope that helps.

Callbacks are used for asynchronous javascript, otherwise you get race conditions (what you were seeing).

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call is asynchronous, which means that when you set title the server is still processing your request. When you put the unwanted alert, you stop the client for awhile, and the server answer the request, that's why it works.

If you put the code in the success, as stated above, it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
var _song_title = ''
$(".watch_view img").each(function() {    
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/T2aMBeeM4yw?v=2&alt=jsonc',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {   
    _song_title = json.data.title;// song title is retrieved without issue                           
    }   
    }).done(function(){
        alert(_song_title); //this to be removed
   //the title attr below is only added when the above alert is in place    
   $(this).attr('title', _song_title);
   $(this).attr('alt', "This works everytime");
    });
```